# My threadspool just make 4~5threads. why?

Tags: c++, multithreading, threadpool, queueuserworkitem

I use QueueUserWorkItem() function to invoke threadpool.
And I tried lots of work with it. (about 30000)
but by the task manager my application only make 4~5 thread after I push the start button.
I read the MSDN which said that the default number of thread limitation is about 500.
why just a few of threads are made in my application?
I'm tyring to speed up my application and I dout this threadpool is the one of reason that slow down my application.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to understand how the threadpool scheduler works.  It was designed to fine-tune the number of *running* threads against the capabilities of your machine.  Your machine probably can run only two threads at the same time, dual-core CPUs are the current standard.  Maybe four.

So when you dump a bunch of threads in its lap, it starts out by activating only two threads.  The rest of them are in a queue, waiting for CPU cores to become available.  As soon as one of those two threads completes, it activates another one.  Twice a second, it evaluates what's going on with active threads that didn't complete.  It makes the rough assumption that those threads are blocking and thus not making progress and allows another thread to activate.  You've now got three running threads.  Getting up the 500 threads, the default max number of threads, will take 249 seconds.

Clearly, this behavior spells out what a thread should do to be suitable to run as a threadpool thread.  It should complete quickly and don't block often.  Note that blocking on I/O requests is dealt with separately.

If this behavior doesn't suit you then you can use a regular Thread.  It will start running right away and compete with other threads in your program (and the operating system) for CPU time.  Creating 30,000 of such threads is not possible, there isn't enough virtual memory available for that.  A 32-bit operating system poops out somewhere south of 2000 threads, consuming all available virtual memory.  You can get about 50,000 threads on a 64-bit operating system before the paging file runs out.  Testing these limits in a production program is not recommended.

Comment: Yes I found out that my machine has four core. w/o threadpool my application runs 4 times slower.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have misunderstood the use of the threadpool.  Spawning threads and killing threads involves the Windows Kernel and is an expensive operation.  If you continuously need threads to perform an aynchronous operation and then you throw them away it would perform many system calls.

So the threadpool is actually a group of threads which are created *once* which instead of exiting when they complete their task actually enter a wait for another item for queueuserworkitem.  The threadpool will then tune itself based on how many threads are required concurrently for your process.  If you wish to test this write this code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 30000; i++)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(myMethod);
}
```

You will see this will create a whole bunch of threads.  Maybe not 30000 as some of the threads that are created will be reused as the ThreadPool starts to work through your function calls.

Answer (score 0):

The threadpool is there so you can avoid creating a thread for every asynchronous operation for the very reason that threads are expensive. If you want 30,000 threads you're going to use a lot of memory for the thread stacks plus waste a lot of CPU time doing context switches. Now creating that many threads would be justified if you had 30,000 CPU cores...